# Change rows to columns based on key ID's

Tags: spss

So here's an example of what I have, and an explanation of what I am looking for. I can't seem to get the restructure function in SPSS to work properly, could be the wrong tool for the job. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

- ID | Car_Make | Car_Model
- 999, Subaru, WRX
- 867, Volvo, 240
- 999,Acura, TSX

---

- ID | Car_Make1 | Car_Model1 | Car_Make2 | Car_Model2.....(Dependent on list)
- 999, Subaru, WRX, Acura, TSX
- 867, Volvo, 240

---

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is a key\index variable.
Try this:

```
* first recreating your sample data.
data list list/ ID (f10) Car_Make  Car_Model (2a20).
begin data
999, "Subaru", "WRX"
867, "Volvo", "240"
999,"Acura", "TSX"
end data.

* now creating an index and restructuring.
sort cases by ID.
compute ind=1.
format ind(f2).
if $casenum>1 and ID=lag(ID) ind=lag(ind)+1.
casestovars /id=ID/index=ind/sep="_".
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Why wouldn't the ID variable work as key/index?

Comment: As you see the casestovars command uses ID variables and INDEX variables. Together they determine the new structure of the data. The index isn't really necessary for your needs but the command won't function without it so we create an artificial one just for that.

Comment: That worked on the test data, now I just need to adjust to meet my specific needs. Thank you very much!